# How to deal with memory leak due to hashmap in Java

Tags: java, plugins, hashmap, heap-memory

I am developing a plugin. Where i am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. I tried increasing the size of the heap where it works with less data but with large data it fails. I tried analyzing the memory leak using MAT and it seems hashmap is causing this issue.

[image]

I am using hashmap like below in almost all my classes to get some property from files. Here the hasmap contains some constant like project root and some key value pair of constants.

```
 Key                        Value
Project_root               D:/..
CAT_Product                Product Category
```

What alternative i can use for hashmap or should i clean data in hashmap.
I am pretty not sure what could be the ideal solution for this.

```
private final HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();

public void execute() {
    this.mistlogger = MistLogger.getInstance();
    MIST.ROOT = this.properties.get(Constants.ROJECT_ROOT_DIR);
    this.updateData = ProjectAnalyzer.getCatalogDetails(MIST.ROOT, Constants.Unit);
    this.files = this.properties.get(Constants.FILES);
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to the question: What data are you holding in the HashMap? How is data loaded in the map? how long do you need the hashmap data?

Comment: Added it @GoviS

Comment: If you have predefined or the values in you hashmap doesn't change.. try making it static so that it won't be created for each instance

Comment: How about weak hashmap ? @SabareeshMuralidharan

Comment: I don't think weakhashmap would be used here a lot as the key (String) is not going out of ref so that GC can clean it

Comment: ok. I am trying with static will see. @SabareeshMuralidharan

Comment: I tried but it does not work. @SabareeshMuralidharan

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options to try which may help extend the life of your application, before it hits OutOfMemoryError again.

Firstly there is always the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` memory options to extend  the memory used by VM.

If your app loads its a lot of strings from database or files rather than declarations `String x = "value"` (which are already `intern` version), you might try calling `String.intern()` to get internal form of strings. This will only help if the same set of String keys and values are often repeated across different HashMaps, or any of the values in your application.

```
map.put(key.intern(), value.intern());
```

HashMap auto-extends its internal buffers when it reaches its loadfactor size, so you often see get OOM in `map.put()` when it is copying OLD to NEW table. You could force the contructor for HashMap fix a large `tablesize` and 1.0f loadfactor. I think this prevents auto-extend but wastes storage if `map.size()` is much smaller than tablesize AND it slows down each retrieval if `map.size()` is much bigger than tablesize.

```
private final HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>(tablesize, 1.0f);
```

However you should think carefully about what is essential memory storage footprint versus what data you can dump + reload on demand, and might also consider `SoftReference` for items that aren't essential to hold onto, a timestamp to identify old data, `map.remove` on unnecessary data and so help GC clean up at the expense that you have to re-load later.